# 3D Transformation Resolution Issue

Tags: html, css, 3d, transform

When using an X or Y rotation on an element while I have a perspective set on the parent element, the resolution of the transformed element seems to drop to a stretched bitmap version of the original element rather than maintaining its own resolution.

When the X/Y rotations are removed, this distortion doesn't happen. Z rotations seem to be handled just fine without a drop in resolution. If perspective is turned off, the resolution seems to be normal as well.

Example:
http://dabblet.com/gist/4068590

```
/* # Bug # */
/* Removing the perspective gets rid of the resolution drop */
body { perspective: 200px; }

/*/ 
 * X and Y rotations cause the resolution to drop
 * while the Z rotation doesn't 
/*/
#test {
    transform: scaleX(5) scaleY(5) rotateX(2deg);
}
```

This seems to happen in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari (XP). Is there any way to work around this? (Besides increasing the size of the original element and then scaling it down)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're running into GPU vs. non-GPU transformations. When something is handed to the GPU, it takes a rasterized copy of the whatever it's handed then stretches, squeezes and interpolates pixels. Since it's up to the browser to decide what to hand off to the GPU, you have to jedi mind trick the browser into not doing GPU offloading (YMMV). Or, as you suggest, use large elements/images and set the maximum scale = 1.